# Get a list of network folders and the path to them

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command

help write a script in .bat or .PS1
The task is as follows:
You need to get a list of network folders shared on the local network in (workgroup)

I wrote the following, but the script displays me a list of local shares:

list.txt (echo Sh_Dir       Sh_Path& echo --------------------& net share|findstr [:\])

Comment: A quick search would show that there are many examples all over the web and on Youtube for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Continuing from my comment.***

For example:

[Listing Network Drives](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/listing-network-drives-2)

There are many ways to list mapped network drives. One of them uses
PowerShell’s Get-PSDrive and checks to see whether the target root starts with
“\”, indicating a UNC network path:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | 
Where-Object DisplayRoot -like '\\*'
# Results
<#
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                    CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                    ---------------
Z               11076,55          0,00 FileSystem    \\192.168.2.107\docs  
#>
```

One nice touch is that Get-PSDrive returns useful additional details such as
the size of the drive.